# Flatten nested array with type inference

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, flatten

I am trying to create a function that can flatten nested arrays in typescript.

So far I have this:

```
function flattenArrayByKey<T, TProp extends keyof T>(array: T[], prop: TProp): T[TProp] {
    return array.reduce((arr: T[TProp], item: T) => [...arr, ...(item[prop] || [])], []);
}
```

The `array.reduce` in there does exactly what I want as is, but I can't get the generics to play along nicely with what I want. I think my problem is that `item[prop]` returns `any` since it has no way of inferring that `item[prop]` returns `T[TProp]`.

What I'm aiming for is a function that can take this structure:

```
interface MyInterface {
    arrayProperty: string[];
    anotherArray: number[]
    someNumber: number;
}

const objectsWithNestedProperties: MyInterface[] = [
    {
        arrayProperty: ['hello', 'world'],
        anotherArray: [1, 2],
        someNumber: 1,
    },
    {
        arrayProperty: ['nice', 'to'],
        anotherArray: [3, 4],
        someNumber: 2,
    },
    {
        arrayProperty: ['meet', 'you'],
        anotherArray: [5, 6],
        someNumber: 3,
    },
];
```

and return an array that contains the contents of all the nested array.

```
const result = flattenArrayByKey(objectsWithNestedProperties, 'arrayProperty');
```

`result` should look like `['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']`

Basically I am looking for `SelectMany` from C#'s linq.

Comment: `Array.flat()` already works in some modern browsers

Comment: @Kokodoko that doesn't let me specify which nested array I want to flatten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: The following answer was tested on TS3.5 in `--strict` mode.  Your mileage may vary if you use other versions or compiler flags.

---

How about this:

```
function flattenArrayByKey<K extends keyof any, V>(array: Record<K, V[]>[], prop: K): V[] {
    return array.reduce((arr, item) => [...arr, ...(item[prop] || [])], [] as V[]);
}
```

You have to tell the compiler that `T[TProp]` was going to be an array.  Instead of trying to go that route, I have the generics be `K` (which you were calling `TProp`) and `V`, the element type of the array property at `array[number][K]`.  Then you can type `array` as `Record<K, V[]>[]` instead of `T[]` (A `Record<K, V[]>` is an object whose property at key `K` is of type `V[]`).  And it returns a `V[]`.

Now the compiler understands what you're trying to do, although you do need to tell it that the initial empty array as the second parameter to `reduce` is supposed to be a `V[]` (hence `[] as V[]`).

And that should work how you want.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMANgQylApmAggJ3zQE8AhYgaS2IB4LEsAPbMAEwGdEBrauYRNGGIAaRADUAfAAoAUIgGESALkQAlLBDj5WdUWIDaAXQlHhcxAAd8cCyooyAlCoOHEAb3P4sUEPiRpFYgA6L1YQCCxZeXkpAPxRGGwAWwdEAF4JRH0gnLjRHKCpRKwk-SsbVwAfSqzDB0MzaNqBThdzBwBuGQBfGRgwbHxgNAjEAFliAEkBrCGRrHdzOJIABWsLWahiFXYofH6AcyMu+UE4KAALWYIibcQwECSAI1nj83Y4JKwAOUeX-BUD2esy6vRkmjAu0QcCeACsNFB2AB1RIXb5YXZYVhrGybGAYlQTaaDYYRIzpLLmDxNZbEHEbfBbFT6ABEVxQKDgLNELIA7loUKwWQ1zKcwOcrvgbsosgBGUQAJhFTQ+X1+wIBiFl5m6jUWNMC9M2d1ZYBgEW5iBZUC5yuiZ0u10CzIAzKIACx2+Sqn5-WYqBU6vXU+2G9bG5ksr7eS0s4hwEDCvViiVO27MgCsogAbF7ED71f8VC6dTJDF1wQgoV52CAUFAAMp7Q7S4gU1AYFit8hUYhRaFwhHI1HozHY8OM-HsPUs2lGxnEFmODqIAD0q+hXBIMkrkKgiBrdagAHkbJw0sh0JgcN3KNR+zD4dBh5dR9hx7jJxjRGuN7NrPgACE5izuKjpSoES6dL+iC8hcGAAPw7hC1YYkehZpiQ7ZXl2gQ9tQNCgamEG3JaQL-NI5iPkOKKvhi77zrA34gQ6kqtlBK7rpuWFPCA+6hOArCCFAu4fCgWBBJyBxSIe9YYSRJCdDIQA)

**Update:** the above seems not to infer well when the object has arrays of different types.  You might find yourself having to type it explicitly like `flattenArrayByKey<"anotherArray", number>(objectsWithNestedProperties, "anotherArray")` which is redundant and annoying.

The following is a more complicated signature but it has better inference and better IntelliSense suggestions:

```
type ArrayKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? K : never }[keyof T];

function flattenArrayByKey<T extends Record<K, any[]>, K extends ArrayKeys<T>>(
  array: T[],
  prop: K
): T[K][number][] {
  return array.reduce(
    (arr, item) => [...arr, ...(item[prop] || [])],
    [] as T[K][number][]
  );
}
```

It should behave the same in terms of the inputs and outputs, but if you start typing

```
const result = flattenArrayByKey(objectsWithNestedProperties, "");
// put cursor here and get intellisense prompts (ctrl-spc) ---^
```

It will suggest `"arrayProperty"` (and now `"anotherArray"`) as the second parameter, since only `arrayProperty` (and `"anotherArray"`) is suitable for reducing like that.

Hope that helps again.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiA0hEBnAPAFQHxQC8UA3lANopQCWAdlANboD2AZlDgLoBcHlnUCAA9gEWgBMMURLRDkBAfihVetCADcIcKAF9yTEGw6cA3ACgzrAK60AxsGrN6rADaJgo2vCQgAQqnRcQRExSSgAJQhbZjhxLBQAGmlZeTwkqmFPMO9kNExcPDwACjMoaQRkXhx5BNKoMDhmMF4UMwBKKv5yWisAWwAjLU55Ujq4CGArOHpECpAAOnHxK1sIErKyotm4JOpRXraiAnJ50+2k0-mivYhe8gamgQAfJ4pONs5ajbfpKWqUYY9AZDeR1NrmHQWOiiOCsRCrKAAWRAAElaDC4QiSHVtsgAAqNSBwUC8DDAOB0ADm8nMZRkzGAAAstDkQKo+oM4DS6hhmL0IAA5DladnAuAQizRWhkqDMfoAKyiwAwAHU9oyBRAyRBxASmloHFreMi0Rj4RARsRyHVsd9cSA9USSRQAETMlwuZgupIugDuMRc4hdnzqdNoDOZcFZvHIAEYkgAmEPfXn8oVi3ixuo6L6jO1zR0Gtmu2jUVbeqAu4Be5MbelMllzGMAZiSABZa2VU4LhXBeAns7nbXWC4SizGXfyJhWXYYrMHc2GI42fDGAKxJABsnag3fTnN4zezZlMFjMUpl4wwVhcwCIUFc7k8rP8eSKcsV9lV6s12t1Y+JagtR9e1C2JEAXXBc8nF5FwIHmT1KSKK8b2AKCgA)

Comment: The first one isn't accepting my array since it wants a record and I'm not quite understanding what record I'm supposed to be putting in there. The second one returns a union type of all possible arrays.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of what’s not working?  I gave links to the code which do work for your example, so if something is not working I can’t reproduce it.

Comment: I updated the OP with an extra array property, with it the return type is a union of ( string | number).

Comment: Hmmm, it is working on typescript playground but in vscode I get the union type. We are on TS 3.2.4, I wonder if the version has anything to do with it?

Comment: Yes, the second one might not work for 3.2 but the first one should (you can check in the playground by changing the version to... 3.1.6).  The TypeScript language is still under fairly active development and has lots of compiler options, so unless someone mentions otherwise I think I've been assuming the newest version (3.5 right now) with all the `--strict` flags.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, but I think it would be a good idea to mention that you tested it in 3.5 :)

Comment: Tested NOT working in 3.3, I am getting the union type there so definitely something added in 3.4/3.5.

Comment: Hmm, well if you can provide a link that shows your problem I will look at it.  Otherwise I'm having a hard time reproducing what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ESNext has `Array.flatMap` which does exactly what I want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> var new_array = arr.flatMap(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
>    // return element for new_array
> }[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> `callback` Function that produces an element of the new Array, taking three arguments:
>
> > `currentValue`
> >            The current element being processed in the array.
> >
> > `index` (Optional)
> >            The index of the current element being processed in the array.
> >
> > `array` (Optional)
> >            The array map was called upon.
>
> `thisArg` (Optional)
>   Value to use as `this` when executing callback.

To use it, I needed to add `esnext.array` to my `lib` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
         "lib": ["es2018", "dom", "esnext.array"]
     }
}
```

It does exactly what I want:

```
objectsWithNestedProperties.flatMap(obj => obj.arrayProperty)
// returns ['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'to', 'meet', 'you']
```

**NB**: This isn't supported by IE, Edge, and Samsung Internet.